# Recover the prompt from a backgrounded query in MariaDB

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface

Throug SSH, I accessed my MariaDB and started a DELETE query. This SQL are running 8 h continuous and I got a break in my VPN service, losting the connection.

When I reconnected, I saw that SQL continues working, but without the mysql prompt. Have some way to recover this prompt or command again?

Ex:

```
# mysql mydatabase
MariaDB [(mydatabase)]> DELETE <statment>....

<lost connection>
<reconnect ssh session>

# mysql mydatabase
MariaDB [(mydatabase)]> show processlist;
+-------+-------------+---------------------+--------+---------+--------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id    | User        | Host                | db     | Command | Time   | State               | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+-------+-------------+---------------------+--------+---------+--------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|     1 | system user |                     | NULL   | Sleep   | 104644 | closing tables      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|     2 | system user |                     | NULL   | Sleep   | 104644 | wsrep aborter idle  | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 11230 | root        | localhost           | matomo | Query   |  49693 | Sending data        | DELETE matomo_log_visit, matomo_log_link_visit_action, matomo_log_conversion, matomo_log_conversion_ |    0.000 |
....

MariaDB [(mydatabase)]>
```

My query is there, with Id 11230, but I haven´t more the prompt. Is possible to recover this query to my current mariadb prompt?

Comment: Yes, if you use `tmux` or a similar tool (for example in old days we used `screen`). Otherwise, no. If you lose your ssh session, you cannot reconnect to it.